# Steps to upgrade in Symfony 2.1 using composer

Tags: symfony-2.1, composer-php

I just testing new features on symfony 2.1-BETA3. Few hours ago BETA4 has been released but I don't know how to update BETA3 to BETA4 using composer. In 2.0.x release notes Fabien said:

> If you already have a project based on the Symfony Standard Edition 2.0.x, you can easily upgrade to 2.0.15 by getting the new deps and deps.lock files.

Have I replace my composer.lock file? What about my own requires like:

```
"package": "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle",
"version": "dev-master",
"source-reference": "36356b158b74cb68f96dc0b657e8732422b9d5dd",
"commit-date": "1341954345"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't touch `composer.lock`! Change `composer.json`. If you are using the standard edition, you probably already have something like

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.1.*"
```

and

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

in there. The later one means, that you allow dev packages to get installed. The first one means, that you want *any* `2.1.*` version. You can change it to

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.1.0-BETA4"
```

if you want, but the original `2.1.*` should be suffice right now. Now call

```
php composer.phar update
```

This will update `composer.lock` too. Now you maybe must call (must say: I've forgotten it) call

```
php composer.phar install
```

to install the dependencies from `composer.lock`.

In short:

```
# To install (maybe even after update)
$ php composer.phar install
# To update 
$ php composer.phar update
# To add, remove or change dependencies
# edit composer.json
$ php composer.phar update
```

YOu never need to touch `composer.lock` yourself and you shouldn't to avoid side effects of composer.

Comment: mmm...Basically, I don't have to touch anything. Leaving "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*" in composer.json and running "php composer.phar update" works.

Comment: Yes :) As long as I don't "seriously" deploy my application I do it the same way: From time to time `composer.phar update` and commit the updated `composer.lock` into the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Download the composer in symfony2 root folder:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

and execute

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar update
```

use this if you can update to the last version.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other things to do on top of what @KingCrunch told you, for instance the namespace of Doctrine has changed, some nodes in the configuration files (security.yml, config.yml) have changed from 2.0.* to 2.1.*

You should read this [README](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md) on the symfony2 github repository as it explains in details what changed between sf 2.0 and sf 2.1

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey!. I have installed standard-edition BETA3. Differences are between sf 2.0 and sf 2.1. Or 2.1-BETA3 and 2.1-BETA4 too?

Comment: Oh my bad I thought you were switching from sf2.0 to sf2.1, in this case @KingCrunch solution is the best one